# Detect page is loaded into Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way for a web part to figure out the hosting page is being loaded into SharePoint Designer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the web part control's DesignMode property—it's true if it's open in SPD.  This should work for all ASP.NET controls.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WSS 3.0 / MOSS 2007, Yes:

```
SPContext.Current.IsRemoteAuthoringTime
```

or, depending on your context,

```
SPContext.Current.IsDesigntime
```

Update: A cruder way might be to peek at the HttpRequest headers - I'm sure SPD sents a header.

-Oisin